# Orthogonal eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We have
$
B = \frac 13
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$.
This is a symmetric matrix, so we should be able to get a set of orthonormal eigenvectors. I find $ \lambda $'s equal to $1, 0 ,0$ and the corresponding eigenvectors
$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        1 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix},
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 \\
        1 \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$
, which are independent (even though one eigenvalue is repeated) but not orthogonal. Somehow, I can't immediately see how to get orthonormal vectors from the ones I produced.

Comment: Apply Gram-Schmidt's Process. You can google, though if you were asked to do this you should have already covered in class...and in this case is easy as eigenvectors corresponding to *different* eigenvalues **of a symmetric matrix** are already orthogonal...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you find $(-1,0,1)$ and $(-1,1,0)$ as "the" eigenvectors for eigenvalue $0$, that is a bit misstated -- because there's a whole $2$-dimensional subspace of eigenvectors with eigenvalue $0$. What you have is merely two more or less random vectors that span this subspace, but if you instead choose two *orthogonal* spanning vectors, then you can use those in an orthogonal eigenbasis.

You can either carry out the Gram-Schmidt procedure as DonAntonio suggested in a comment, or just apply a small bit of ad-hoc reasoning.

What you're looking for is two perpendicular $(x,y,z)$ such that $x+y+z=0$. We can let one of them be $(-1,0,1)$ which you've already found, so for the other one to be perpendicular to it, you need $-x+z=0$. Thus we want a nonzero solution to
$$ x+y+z=0 \\ x=z $$
which is easily solved to get $(1,-2,1)$ (or something proportional to this).

Finally, of course, you need to normalize each of these eigenvectors if you want an ortho*normal* eigenbasis.

Comment: It was that "little bit of reasoning" I was looking for. Thanks! One more question, though. How do I know that after Gram-Schmidt (or simply "finding" a third orthogonal vector) the vector I get is still an eigenvector of $B$? I suspect that this follows from the properties of symmetric matrices (there is an orthonormal eigenbasis and since we already have two orthogonal vectors, the third one will automatically belong to that eigenbasis) but I would like to confirm.

Comment: @Zelazny: You would know it _automatically_ if you're use Gram-Schmidt _separately_ on each eigenspace. It's a bit more involved if you're using Gram-Schmidt on a complete eigenbasis with all the eigenvalues represented. Then you'd need to dig into how Gram-Schmidt works internally and use the fact that different eigenspaces of a symmetric matrix are already known to be perpendicular to each other.